# 64GB available, cv2/python crash when exceeding 16GB

Tags: python, opencv

I am loading many images into memory because I need to iterate over them very often to perform random data augmentation when training a neural network. My machine has 64GB of memory and more than 60GB are available. The machine runs a 64bit Linux and Python 3.7.4.

My script runs until the process exceeds 16GB. Then I see this error message:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2)/tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474/work/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:55: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 18874368 bytes **[this are 18MB]** in
>   function 'OutOfMemoryError'

Is there an internal memory limit for cv2 and/or python?

I also tried the following with numpy:

```
a = np.zeros((16*1024*1024*1024,), dtype=np.uint8)+1
```

(works and allocates 16GB)

```
a = np.zeros((17*1024*1024*1024,), dtype=np.uint8)+1
```

(crashes)

So I think it is a python or numpy issue as cv2 uses numpy internally.

Interestingly I am able to allocate >16GB using pytorch:

```
a = torch.ones((28*1024*1024*1024,), dtype=torch.uint8)
```

(works, but fails when I try more than 28GB)

Forgot to mention that I am running everything inside a SLURM instance. But I don't know how to find out if that is the issue because I have no other machine with that amount of memory.

EDIT: Before loading each image I print the memory information using psutil. This is right before it crashes:

> svmem(total=134773501952, available=116365168640, percent=13.7, used=17686675456, free=112370987008, active=18417344512, inactive=2524413952, buffers=176410624, cached=4539428864, shared=87986176, slab=371335168)

Comment: note that your first example allocates much more than 16GB!  it creates one 16GB array filled with zeros then allocates another 16GB array to store the result of `+1` into.  you have to be somewhat more careful of when working with objects this large :)  check out `numpy.full` or use `a += 1` which mutates the matrix and hence doesn't need the second allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not related to Python and/or OpenCV. My `ulimit -v` setting was too low. Running `ulimit -v unlimited` solves the problem.